# Self-built Bonobo.Git.Server Login Error: The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present

Tags: windows-server-2016, bonobo

I got the below error while logging in with admin/admin after first open the Bonobo server:

```
500 Server Error

A server error occurred when processing your request. Please try again or contact the system administrator.
```

Bonobo version: **V6.5.0**

Server: **Windows Server 2016 Standard**

And I have tried serial ways but no luck:

1. Add `<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true"/>` in web.config
2. Move the folder out of C:\inetpub\wwwroot;
3. Re-open the browser;

After googled hours in internet, it seems that the root reason is code issue. **could anyone can help me out of this?**

Below is the log copied from Bonobo.Git.Server\App_Data\Logs:

```
2020-04-22 11:54:24.061 +08:00 [Error] 500 Exception caught in Global.asax
System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException (0x80004005): The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.
   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.TokenValidator.ValidateTokens(HttpContextBase httpContext, IIdentity identity, AntiForgeryToken sessionToken, AntiForgeryToken fieldToken)
   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryWorker.Validate(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1c(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Have you tried a different browser?  This is a very low-level problem to do with anti XSRF-protection which is provided by the framework, and it isn't being reported by other people.

Comment: @Will Dean Thank you for your response. I have tried it with IE/Chrome/Edge and all got the same issue. So I try to download the source codes from https://github.com/jakubgarfield/Bonobo-Git-Server, and it works in both debug mode and publish mode after re-built. So I am considering that maybe there have some compatibility issue in the ZIP package downloaded from http://bonobogitserver.com. Any suggestion? I should use the formal package in my server, instead of thelocal publish version. Thank you again.